# A basic question on contours/level sets of a function in quadratic form

Tags: optimization

Consider 
$$f(x)=\frac{1}{2}x^TQx-x^Tb$$

where $Q$ is an $n \times n$ symmetric matrix

The contours of $f$ are $n-$dimensional ellipsoids with axes in the directions of the $n$-mutually orthogonal eigenvectors of $Q$. What is the meaning of this statement ?

Comment: Try to work it out for the special case of $2\times 2$ matrix.

Comment: Which parts of the statement don't you understand?  Do you know what an $n$-dimensional ellipsoid is?  Do you know what an axis of such an ellipsoid is?  Do you know what an eigenvector is?  Do you know what mutually orthogonal means?

Comment: I am guessing that $Q$ is positive definite. Take $Q$ to be diagonal and $b=0$ to start.

Comment: Take $Q=identity$ and $n=2$ and $b=[{1\atop 1}]$   $x=[{x_1\atop x_2}]$. Then $f(x)=1/2(x_1^2+x_2^2)-(x_1+x_2)$. Contour level means solution of $f(x)=C$ for some number $C$. Now in this case you get a simple circle. Next try $Q$ a diagonal matrix with diagonal entries $1,2$ to see what happens.